# Cannot share sessions between Docker Flask apps behind reverse proxy

Tags: python, docker, flask, session, cookies

**TL, DR:** Two Flask apps, *Authenticator* and *Main*, are on separate containers but have the same origin thanks to a reverse proxy (Traefik). *Authenticator* successfully gets the authentication token, saves it to the `session` dictionary in *Authenticator*. The same-origin policy tells me that browser would send the session dictionary as a cookie upon redirect to *Main*, but the session dictionary in *Main* remains empty afterwards. The `session` dictionary in *Main* doesn't update although the `session` (hash?) value in the *Main* cookie is identical to that of *Authenticator*, i.e., cookies are sent to both. (I tried with dummy cookies and they got sent). How do I force `session` in *Main* to update?

**Fuller Explanation**

I have two Flask applications (*authenticator* and *main*) each running in a Docker container. The two containers live behind a reverse proxy (Traefik) so that `localhost` routes to *main*, `localhost/authenticate || localhost/getAToken` to *authenticator*. The authenticator successfully communicates with MSAL to obtain the authentication token, which I save in the `session` dict, i.e., the following (AAD redirect_uri points to here, in *authenticator*) works:

```py
# authenticator app
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
            session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
        ...
        resp = make_response(redirect("http://localhost")) # goes to main
```

However, on *main*'s side of things, the `session` dictionary is empty, although it seems that the cookies are behaving properly wrt the same origin policy: `request.cookies['session']` in *main* and *authenticator* are identical and setting a non-Session cookie is accessible to both web apps.

```py
# main app (index)
...
if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect("http://localhost/authenticate") # goto authenticator
...
```

How do I force the Sessions dict in the main app to update its values? Or, would it make more sense to use a Redis store, e.g., to handle Session information?

**Related Questions**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42888376 I'm basically implementing the first mechanism proposed in this soln.
- [Share session data between Flask apps in separate Docker containers that are served using a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222428/share-session-data-between-flask-apps-in-separate-docker-containers-that-are-ser) (has no soln)